# how to display webpages from multiple different directories using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, networking

I'm trying to run a few different sites on an ubuntu server which I'm connected to via a public connection. There's supposed to be a main site and 2 sub-sites. Currently, the important part of the directory is laid out as follows:

```
.
|---index.js
|--_node_modules
   └---(all the node modules)
|---package-lock.json
|--_Public
   |---index.html
   └---(required folders & files for index.html)
|--_A
   └--_folder
      |---index.html
      └---(required folders & files for index.html)
|--_B
   └--_folder
      |---index.html
      └---(required folders & files for index.html)
```

My index.js has the following code:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        app.use(express.static(path.resolve('/public')))
        res.sendFile('index.html')
})

app.get('/a', (req, res) => {
        app.use(express.static(path.resovle('/A/folder')))
        res.sendFile('index.html')
})

app.get('/b', (req, res) => {
        app.use(express.static(path.resolve('/B/folder')))
        res.sendFile('index.html')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('Running server on port ' + port)
})
```

With this way of implementing index.js, none of the sites work at all.

When I type "(public_ip):3000", "(public_ip):3000/a" or "(public_ip):3000/b" it gives me:

**Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/index.html'**

---

I also tried my index.js as the following:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.static('./public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile('/index.html')
})

app.get('/a', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile('/index.html', {root: 'A/folder'})
})

app.get('/b', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile('/index.html', {root: 'B/folder'})
})

app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('Running server on port ' + port)
})
```

This will result in "(public_ip):3000" working perfectly.
The only issue from here is that now "(public_ip):3000/a" and "(public_ip):3000/b" only rendered the html and can't find any of the other files, with the following errors in the console:

```
Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet 
MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://(public ip):3000/A/folder/css/animate.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://(public ip):3000/A/folder/css/icomoon.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://(public ip):3000/A/folder/css/bootstrap.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://(public ip):3000/A/folder/css/flexslider.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://(public ip):3000/A/folder/css/owl.carousel.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://(public ip):3000/A/folder/css/owl.theme.default.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://(public ip):3000/A/folder/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://(public ip):3000/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://(public ip):3000/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://(public ip):3000/css/resume.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://(public ip):3000/css/font-mfizz.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://(public ip):3000/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://(public ip):3000/css/resume.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://(public ip):3000/css/font-mfizz.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://(public ip):3000/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
a:46 GET http://(public ip):3000/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
a:864 GET http://(public ip):3000/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
a:868 GET http://(public ip):3000/js/jquery.countTo.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
a:871 GET http://(public ip):3000/js/portfolio.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
2a:1 GET http://(public ip):3000/images/aboutme.jpg 404 (Not Found)
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://(public ip):3000/js/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
a:864 GET http://(public ip):3000/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
a:868 GET http://(public ip):3000/js/jquery.countTo.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
main.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).stellar is not a function
    at main.js:6
    at main.js:245
(anonymous) @ main.js:6
(anonymous) @ main.js:245
a:871 GET http://(public ip):3000/js/portfolio.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

As you can see in the error, I set some of my html links and scripts with the path from the index.js file (ex: A/folder/css/animate.css) and the rest from the index.html file (ex: js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js).

It seems neither of these worked so I don't know what else to try. Hopefully this is all the information for someone to know what the issue is. If not, I'm sure you'll let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use multiple static assets directories, call the `express.static` middleware function multiple times. Besides, we can create a virtual path prefix (where the path does not actually exist in the file system) for files that are served by the `express.static` function, specify a mount path for the static directory. We use virtual path prefix to distinguish different folders(A,B,public).

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './public')));
app.use('/a', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './A/folder')));
app.use('/b', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './B/folder')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public') });
});

app.get('/a', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'A/folder') });
});

app.get('/b', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'B/folder') });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Running server on port ' + port);
});
```

`A/folder/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/a/css/style.css">
  <title>A</title>
</head>
<body>
  A
</body>
</html>
```

`A/folder/css/style.css`:

```css
body {
  background: red;
}
```

The files in the B directory are the same as the A directory.

`public/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/resume.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  From public
</body>
</html>
```

`public/css/resume.css`:

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/65398400